# Create a variable at very top of long SAS code series

Tags: sas

I have a long SAS program.  In the MIDDLE somewhere I use Proc Rank, groups=4....

```
proc rank
data=nicholas.combined
out=nicholas.ranks
groups=4; var _23603 _23604 ; run ;
```

What I'd really like to do is put a variable, or marker, or something, at the very beginning of the program:

Grp=4 ;

And then in the middle of the long program, put:

groups=Grp ;

And have SAS remember back to what I put at the very beginning.

In this case I am not creating a dataset.  Just putting in something I want SAS to remember.

Is this possible in some way?

Thanks!

Nicholas

Answer (score 2):

Just define [macro variable](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002047074.htm):

```
%let GRP = 4;
```

Then you can call proc rank

```
proc rank
data=nicholas.combined
out=nicholas.ranks
groups=&GRP.; var _23603 _23604 ; run ;
```